# LISP: Omit first value in list by reference

Tags: lisp, clisp

I just want to omit first value of list using a function but below code is returning same list
I dont want to return from a fucntion
Code:

```
 #! /usr/bin/clisp    

(defun omit(lstold)
    (setf lstold (cdr lstold))
)
(setq x (list 3 1 2))
(omit x)
(write x)  --> gives output 3 1 2 ... why?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you didn't modify your `x`, but you just modified your local `lstold`, and you returned it to nowhere (i.e. didn't capture returned value).